# Ajax form only submits once - requires page refresh after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have a form which submits successfully via ajaxForm();, but only submits once.  To get it to submit again, it requires me to refresh the page.

I am trying to allow users to save the form multiple times in one session without refreshing the page, and even put in a auto save function.

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#create-card-process').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('You successfully added a new entry with entry_id '+data.entry_id);
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                alert('Failed with the following errors: '+data.errors.join(', '));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors at all.  Form submits successfully - but when you submit again, absolutely nothing happens!

Comment: if you use this: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object  there are clearForm: true or resetForm: true properties.

Comment: I've tried all of those and still nothing.  Ive noticed that new XHR's are created on each submission, but nothing happens.  Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  A security module being used within the CMS was causing a security conflict when the user submitted duplicate data.

Removing this solves the issue!